# Updating iPhone 4, from iOS 4 to iOS 6

Tags: windows-7, itunes, iphone, ios

I am having a bit of a painful situation here..
I offered to update a iphone for a friend.

We just had reinstalled his computer, so we had no prior backups in iTunes.
However, when the update process to iOS 6 started, iTunes made a backup. At least, that's what it said it was doing.

When the restore was done, iTunes returned an error (I believe 1611, but I'm not sure)

However in the settings I see no backups, if I proceed manually to the iTunes backup folder there isn't anything either...

Where did iTunes save this backup? Or does anyone have a solution to get the iPhone working again (with preservation of data)

Comment: What is the state of the phone? Does it start but is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually managed to use TinyUmbrella to kick it out of recovery mode, with succes.
Thank god.